# Java Details about Variables and References

Tags: java, pointers, reference, stack

As far as I understand it, Java stores variables inside methods in the local variables array on the stack. Those variables can contain primitives or references to objects. Primitives are the value itself, while references are used to access objects on the heap. It seems like the JVM specification supports this idea. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se18/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6.1

> A single local variable can hold a value of type boolean, byte, char,
> short, int, float, reference, or returnAddress. A pair of local
> variables can hold a value of type long or double.

**However, recently I came across a very detailed post about reference variables, which I don't fully understand:**
https://qr.ae/pvbaNH

> Anyway, coming back to the real question, `reference variables` makes
> no sense. Rather, **variables (and fields) are references**, and
> references are a theoretical concept.

Variables are references? I thought variables contain primitives or reference values. Or does he refer to the resolution of identifiers by the constant pool?

Then he goes on to explain this code:

```
// We are in a method block. 
int a = 5; 
int b = a;
```

with following description:

> The concept is, whenever the language makes you think you're setting a
> reference to another one, you're instead asking to solve that source
> reference (i.e. obtaining its value) and to set that value to the
> target reference.

I don't understand why anyone should think that you are assigning references here. It sounds a bit like the stack stores references only (generally) and those references are being resolved to get the actual value stored somewhere else. I guess he is actually just referring to the identifiers 'a' and 'b' being resolved again. Am I correct?

He then goes on explaining how references to objects are stored. This sounds pretty much OK, but he again uses reference ambiguously.

It would be nice if some experienced Java engineer could enlighten my confusion. Please bear with my lack of knowledge.

Comment: That article is pretty blithering, frankly.  (It's on Quora, so I wouldn't expect much.)  I'd ignore it and go with your previous understanding.  That article is definitely trying to "sound smart" by tossing terms around, but uses those terms inappropriately or at least misleadingly, which is a big red flag for me.  I only got about half way through before I decided it was tosh.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. I have a tendency to get lost in details, so this post kind of threw me off due to its (probable) ambiguity.

Comment: And to be clear, from everything you say, you seem to understand how java actually works. Just to reiterate the parts that you got right: Yes, variables are _either_ primitive _or_ reference; primitives are just the value, references are 'addresses' that the JVM can use to 'look up' an object; all objects neccessarily live in the heap and cannot ever be stuffed into a variable, only references to them can be. local vars indeed live in the stack and therefore cannot outlive a method's lifecycle. Objects can, because they live on the heap, not in a variable.

Comment: Whenever you invoke a method, __copies__ of the values are passed. Meaning, if that method then does `myParam = x`, the _caller_ does not see any of its locals change. However, as all values are primitives or references (never objects directly), something like `myParam.setFoo(y)` __is__ observable to callers; you aren't changing `myParam` the variable itself, you are following the reference and asking the object you find there to change itself.

Comment: And all of this is from the "normal" view of code.  Once the optimizer gets involved all bets are off.  Any variable, local or otherwise, could be hoist into a hardware register for speed.  Small heap objects may be allocated on the stack instead ("escape analysis").  Variables may not be passed to a method at all if that method is in-lined (pass-by value semantics are still required tho). The Java spec allows for local variables not allocated on the stack at all but instead on the heap (stack frame vs. activation frame).  Etc.